# Is it safe to use only iptables for security?

Tags: security, iptables

I have 2 servers on different machines. First machine should send requests to second machine via tcp. Both machine have static ip addresses. Does it secure to protect this interaction between servers only by setting iptables rules on second machine?

Comment: Are the two machines in the same LAN or are they separated by (other people's) routers?

Comment: They are separated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not secure the connection between these hosts at all. It lowers the attack surface on the server side when you limit access to daemons as much as you can but it doesnt help you when it comes to connection security.

If possible you should enable SSL to increase the security of the connection. If this isn't possible you might consider setting up an IPSec encrypted connection between both hosts.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But what about iptables as analog of authentication? For example I want to receive messages on the second server only from first server. Is iptables enough for this propose?

Comment: You can limit the incoming packets to the given address. This will increase your security as it is a TCP connectionand IP Spoofing is harden when it comes to TCP because of the 3-Way-Handshake.

Comment: But iptables cannot help you be safe in case of IP spoofing or in case of MITM. You should consider of using SSL/TLS and authentization on application level